# .htaccess rewrite rule is wrong

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I'm trying to write .htaccess rewrite rules for my site.

1. menu links must be shown in address bar like that;
    www.abc.com/**First**, www.abc.com/**Second**
    those links must be rooted to page.php?m=First
2. news details shown in seperate pages
    www.abc.com/**news**/**15**, www.abc.com/**news**/**98**
    those links must be rooted to news.php?id=15
3. other files like index.php mustn't be rewritten.

how can I solve it?

Comment: Paste your existing .htaccess above (edit post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# 3 other files like index.php mustn't be rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# 2 
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
# 1
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ page.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]
```